# Closing a form with End vs Unload me

Tags: vba, excel

It seems both statement works the same. `Unload me` or `End`

can anyone please explain the difference? and purpose of `END` statement

Does both statement do the same thing?

```
Private Sub btn_trial_Click()
SetUpTrial.ActivateTrial (Activation.getMachineIDIndexNo)
End
End Sub
```

Comment: No. But help explains the difference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243356(v=vs.60).aspx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they do not do the same.

- `End` will kill any public or private variable that you have, including any form and any object. Strongly not advisable.
- `Unload Me` should unload the form.

See here for a reference for the form, `Unload Me` is actually not the best option for closing a form and to referring to one in general - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48427044/5448626

Comment: `End` is just unthinkable, unless in debugging.
It won't let `terminate`or `QueryClose` launch at the closing of your UserForm.