# Set values on User Form using form properties

Tags: vba, excel

Appologies if this has been asked already, but I cannot seem to find an answer. I want to set a do something on a UserForm as it is loaded up based on the value passed to it from a property. What I have is a button on an Excel worksheet which loads the user form as follows:

```
 Sub button()
   Dim fm As New UserForm1
   fm.ValueToPass = "Hello"
   fm.Show
 End Sub
```

Behind the form is the following code:

```
Private myString As String

Public Property Let ValueToPass(ByVal x As String)
   myString = x
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   If myString = "Hello" Then
      'Do something on my form
   else
      'Do something else on my form
   end if
End Sub
```

The problem is that when the form is loaded up, the myString is empty. I believe that the reason is that the form is initialised before the property `ValueToPass` is set. What is the best solution to this?

Comment: You could use the Userform's Activate event or, better IMO, use the property to set the label caption if that is all it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably think that when you call:

```
fm.ValueToPass = "Hello"
```

in `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` it is possible that the `myString` value is passed before initializing the form. E.g., you are somehow expecting that `myString` can be something different than `""` (thus you have the condition). This is not the case - first the `_Initialize` constructor is executed and then anything else is carried out:

[image]

With your code, you need somehow to tell the form, that it should update its label. Consider this inside the form:

```
Public Sub ShowForm()

    Me.Label1 = myString
    Me.Show

End Sub
```

Then in the module, call it like `fm.ShowForm` instead of `fm.Show`.

Actually, it is a good idea, if you work with userforms, following the [Model-View-Controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx) pattern. For this you would need a separate class.

[Userform closes after "End Sub" without ever calling "Unload Me"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426349/userform-closes-after-end-sub-without-ever-calling-unload-me/48427044#48427044)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
Sub button()
   Dim fm As New UserForm1
   fm.Label1.Caption = "Hello"
   fm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have been clearer that this is a simplified version of my real problem. I was hoping to be able to pass values so that I can make more significant changes to the form based on the passed value. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Thats more reasonable. But you can access every object without showing/loading the form, so you should be able to access all objects/properties like i've done it here.

Answer (score 1):

you should be using the initialize event for this:

```
Sub OpenForm()
MyForm.show
end sub
```

Then in the initialize event of the userform, put this:

```
Me.LabelName.Caption = "Your label text"
```

(double-click the userform to view its code, then select from the top right drop-down "Initialize".)